# What type of modelling can be used when there are more than 100 levels in one categorical variable?

Tags: r, modeling

First few observations of dataframe. All are categorical with some having levels more than 100.

```
                      ac2.surcat ac2.typeonenum ac2.countrynum ac2.sumnewnum
1          Average survival rate            248            556            16
2             Poor survival rate             82            375            12
3             Poor survival rate             73            104            16
4    Below average survival rate            252           <NA>             6
5             Poor survival rate            252            200            11
6    Below average survival rate            252             83            19
7             Poor survival rate            252            200            12
8             Poor survival rate            210            111             5
9             Poor survival rate            252            178            19
10            Poor survival rate            252            178            18
11            Poor survival rate            230            200             5
```

I know that random forests limits only up to 52 levels. This is an already simplified data. Levels have been reduced from 4000s to 100s. Cannot simplify this further

Dependent variable is `ac2$surcat` (first one)

This is an air crash data. Last 3 columns are 'type of aircraft', 'country' and 'type of crash' respectively.(independent variables)

Comment: You'll need to group the variables

Comment: @Hugh cannot group anymore. this is the limit actually. can I do logistic regression and filter out the less significant variables (keeping only one star). pls help

Comment: You might like to read up on [Freedman's paradox](https://www.r-bloggers.com/freedmans-paradox/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+RBloggers+%28R+bloggers%29) before filtering out the less significant variables

Comment: @Hugh can we do dummy coding on the variables with more than 53 levels?